# How can I get the root terminal to add myself into sudoers file so that I can act as root?

Tags: debian, root, xfce

Once again, I'm trapped in a Linux security circle. When I start terminal, this is what I get:

[image: linux is freaking me out]

So I looked up the internet how to solve it. All solutions unsurprisingly require root permissions. But wait, I can't use `root` because I'm not in the `sudoers` file! So how to get out of this circle?

I'm using Debian with XFCE.

Comment: You aren't listed in the `sudoers` file which means you're not *supposed* to be able to get root access. This sounds completely normal to me!

Comment: Ok, but this is my fresh Debian installation. So I'm pretty damn supposed to configure it. Or do I have special Debian HQ permission to do so? Or are you trolling me? I'm very tired and I'm not posting here for fun.

Comment: If you actually have the root password, just use `su -` ...

Comment: @TomášZato I understand you are tired but I don't appreciate your tone. You didn't say that this was a fresh Debian installation and you didn't mention that you were the rightful owner of the system.

Comment: @Celada In democratic part of the world we are using the innocence presumption approach. It pays off, because if you implicitly assume somebody is doing bad things, he'll not use nice tone when talking to you, especially when he was not doing anything wrong. You could also notice that my installation is called DEBIAN**VPC**.

Comment: What acct did you setup as part of the install? That account should have sudo rights. If jakub is that acct. then try `sudo -Es`. You can see what perms a user has via `sudo` like so: `sudo -l`.

Comment: Yes, the `jakub` should have the permissions indeed. I tend to think the debian release was simply broken - it can happen.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that you were black hat and I'm sorry if I implied it. My reaction was just "system enforcimg security as designed, nothing wrong here". I was figuring maybe your system administrator had forgotten to add you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian installer normally creates the root account plus one normal user account during installation. It sets up the one normal user account with `sudo` access. That way you're supposed to be able to gain root access to your own system after installation. If you cannot, then I can only guess that either:

- you are not using the same user account that was created by the installer, or
- you somehow removed yourself from sudoers, or
- you used some other method than the normal Debian installer to install the system.

One way or the other, you might need to use one of the many available methods to break into your own system:

- Boot the installer again in rescure mode
- Boot in single user mode (if you know the root password)
- Boot with `init=/bin/sh` or similar
- Move the hard drive to another system and reset the root password
- etc...

Comment: I used normal, non-graphic installation. I know the sudo password (I used same as my user password since it's just test virtual installation).

Comment: Try just `su` with that password as suggested by Leiaz. Otherwise I can only guess that something went wrong during installation...

Comment: @TomášZato Yes, there is no "sudo password". The most common setting is for sudo to ask for your user's password. So maybe you did set root's password to the same as your user ?

Comment: @Leiaz Yes, I had my terminology wrong. I meant `root` password.